# What's faster? php calculation or mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I do have a `SQL database` with about 20 columns containing percentage values as decimals, like`0.096303533707682` for example.

On my website **I need to get these values, multiply with 100 and round them up** so that `0.096303533707682` will be shown as `10%` when the page is opened by the user.

Now my question is : is it faster/cheaper to calculate the 10% in advance and save the value to the database, so there is nothing to calculate after the query or doesn't it make much sense or difference ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you benchmark it and see?

Comment: The exact answer to your question is: **It depends!**.

Comment: If your webserver is running on an old computer below your desk, and your database is runing on a 32 core last generation racked server in a datacenter. Which one will be faster? Conclusion: Your question in its actual state has no sense.

Comment: thanks guys! gonna delete this one then :)

Comment: I believe MySql is faster , bcoz it utilizes your allocated RAM and you can set memory size in my.ini , please correct me if i'm wrong anyone .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the individual operation the way to know is: Test it and be aware that performance on both sides can vary between versions and configurations.

On the larger system-level approach mind the following:

- If you transfer data from the database to PHP to then do calculation you probably have extra cost due to networking, thus using SQL and calculating there has benefits.
- Logic can be put into the database, using virtual columns, views or stored procedures/functions, thus multiple applications can share the logic
- However for performance under scale it is simpler to add a new PHP host in front of a database than adding an extra database host.

For this specific question you also have to mind:

- If you have to do the calculations every time maybe you can do this already while storing he data, thus taking more disk space but saving calculation time
- Depending on the amount of data those costs could be quite neglectable and you should rather put it where it makes logically sense. (did you measure and see any problem at all or are you doing premature optimization?) Is the calculation more  like "data retrival" or "business logic"? - This is a subjective choice.